# Respecting excluded index in sum

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, summation, argument-patterns

I'm using a function involving a sum where some indices are excluded:

```
f[s_] := Sum[
   MoebiusMu[n]/n Log[Zeta[n s] (n s - 1)], {n, 
    DeleteCases[Range[1, 10], 1/s]}];
f[1] // N
f'[1] // N
```

`f[1]` works properly, but `f'[1]` yields an error because the exclusion is not respected. If I print `f'[s]` or even `f[s]`, I can see that the excluded index is not actually being excluded in the symbolic expression.

How can I make Mathematica respect the exclusion? I also tried

```
f[s_] := Sum[
   If[n == 1/s, 0, MoebiusMu[n]/n Log[Zeta[n s] (n s - 1)]], {n, 1, 
    10}];
```

But then printing `f'[s]` shows that the `n` are not being substituted into the third argument of `If`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear[f]
```

Use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[s_] := Sum[
   Piecewise[{{MoebiusMu[n]/n Log[Zeta[n s] (n s - 1)],
      n != 1/s}}],
   {n, 1, 10}];

f[1]

(* -(1/2) Log[π^2/6] + 1/6 Log[π^6/189] + 
 1/10 Log[π^10/10395] - 1/3 Log[2 Zeta[3]] - 1/5 Log[4 Zeta[5]] - 
 1/7 Log[6 Zeta[7]] *)

% // N

(* -0.591981 *)

f'[1]
```

[image]

```
% // N

(* -0.850562 *)

Plot[{f'[s], f[s]}, {s, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[{f[s], 0 < s < 10}, s]

(* {-0.777008, {s -> 3.11071}} *)

FindRoot[f'[s] == 0, {s, 3}]

(* {s -> 3.11071} *)
```